# Creating objects based on a type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm quite new to TS and attempting to do something tricky (maybe impossible?)

Here the setup:

- I have those types (`Konva.Layer` is just a `Layer` object in the Konva library, it takes coordinates among other props):

```
type LayerName = "overlays" | "vehicles" | "visual";

type Layers = {   [key in LayerName]: Konva.Layer; };
```

- Then I have the method `instantiateLayers` in which I would like to instantiate Konva layers based on the names defined in `LayerName`.

  That way, if I someone adds a new possible layer in `LayerName`, they do not have to manually change the function.

This is what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
function instantiateLayers(): Layers {
    if (!stage) throw new Error("Stage was not instantiated before the layers");
    
    //First we create an object with the same keys as the Layers type, but no values 
    const layers: Partial<Layers> = {};

    //Then we instantiate the layers by iterating over the keys of the Layers type 
    for (const layerName of Object.keys({} as Layers).map((key) => key as LayerName)) { 
        layers[layerName] = new Konva.Layer({ x: 0, y: 0})
        stage.add(layers[layerName]!);      
    }

    return layers as Layers;
}
```

First off, is what Im trying to do even possible? If yes, what should I change? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Check out Object.fromentries, it may be better for the case

Comment: It would also not work, since types do not get compiled into an object, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Types do not exist at runtime.

```js
const layerNamesObject = ["overlays", "vehicles", "visual"] as const;
type LayerName = (typeof layerNamesObject)[number];


function instantiateLayers(): Layers {
  if (!stage)
    throw new Error("Stage was not instantiated before the layers");

  const layers: Layers = {} as Layers;

  for (const layerName of layerNamesObject) {
    layers[layerName] = new Konva.Layer({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    });

    stage.add(layers[layerName]!);
  }

  return layers as Layers;
}
```